# Convert strange unicode characters into emoji code

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, emoji, mirc

I have a dll i suspect not to be supporting UTF-8 for emojis. (its an addon for mIRC)

This dll changes mIRC (text based chat program), into a full HTML/Javascript.

My problem is, when i receive a message containing emojis, they output like this

`ðŸ˜€`

Four "stange" chars, cause they are not converted fine i suppose.

I though about make a Javascript function matching those, and changing it to correct emoji code back (maybe using a `<span>` or not, since the following code type is translated correctly into smileys `&#x1f608;`)

so, is there any way in javascript to catch/convert `ðŸ˜€` erroneous chars into `&#x1f608;` for example? (those are not the same emoji)

for a correct example :

:grinning face: U+1F600

output this `ðŸ˜€`

sending this `&#x1f600;` finaly output a square... and not the correct smiley so its even not working for all...

Comment: I think you should place a feature request to the developer(s) of the unknown dll you mentioned.